# How to test automate a flight reservation dynamic pricing system using selenium and cucumber

Tags: api, selenium, testing, cucumber

Suppose there is a flight ticket reservation system which calculate the price dynamically on various inputs like source and destination, date which reservation required and booking date etc... If a person books a ticket for a far date it will show less amount and if it is an emergency ticket for the next day or same day it will show a bigger amount how do I create automation scripts using selenium and cucumber for this scenario.

Comment: If you only want to verify the future date will always be cheaper than the 
emergency ticket.

Just create a test case that creates a reservation for the future date store the price generate. Then test using current date and verify the emergency tickets price is greater. If thats all your trying to check.

Comment: why test this through the UI? test this directly through the api?